# Reaction Collector - Get Users to post in an embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Good Evening, I would like some help on how to get the collected users to post in the .setDescription of my embed. For some reason, everything I try to do returns an error or posts object Object or object Map in the description of the embed. As you can see I am getting the console log for the users that have reacted to the post all I want to do now is get all the users and post them in the embed.

At first, u wanted to get all the users and then randomly pair them into a 1v1 battle however I was informed I would need to use a database for them. If anyone could give me some information on that it would be appreciated.

Thank you Ukzs

```js
      .then((channel) => {
        channel.send(embed).then((embedMessage) => {
          embedMessage.react("");
          embedMessage.react("");
          const filter = (reaction, user) => {
            return ["", ""].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && !user.bot;
          };

          const collector = embedMessage.createReactionCollector(filter, {
            time: 10000,
          });

          const destination = guild.channels.cache.find(
            (channel) => channel.name === "t5-battle-channel"
          );

          collector.on("collect", (reaction) => {
            if (reaction.emoji.name === "") {
              console.log(reaction.users);
            }
          });

          collector.on("end", (collected) => {
            if (destination) {
              let embed6 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor("#0099ff")
                .setTitle("⚔️ Members that have joined the T5 Battles! ⚔️")
                .setDescription(`${reaction.fetch("")} Would like to battle!`)
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter("⚔️ 1657 Battles! ⚔️ | ⚔️ Managed by Ukzs⚔️");
              destination.send(embed6);
            }
          });
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
.then((channel) => {
        channel.send(embed).then((embedMessage) => {
          embedMessage.react("");
          embedMessage.react("");
          const filter = (reaction, user) => {
            return ["", ""].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && !user.bot;
          };

          const collector = embedMessage.createReactionCollector(filter, {
            time: 10000,
          });

          const destination = guild.channels.cache.find(
            (channel) => channel.name === "t5-battle-channel"
          );

          collector.on("collect", (reaction) => {
            if (reaction.emoji.name === "") {
              console.log(reaction.users);
            }
          });

          collector.on("end", (collected) => {
            if (destination) {
              let userArr = [];
              let users = collected.first().users.cache.filter(u => !u.bot);
              users.forEach(user => userArr.push(user.username));
              let embed6 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor("#0099ff")
                .setTitle("⚔️ Members that have joined the T5 Battles! ⚔️")
                .setDescription(`${userArr.join(", ")} Would like to battle!`)
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter("⚔️ 1657 Battles! ⚔️ | ⚔️ Managed by Ukzs⚔️");
              destination.send(embed6);
            }
          });
        });
      });
```

I have edited your `collector.on("end"..)` event. I made an Array where the users get stored in. In `users`, all users that are no bots get stored. Then we push every username from the users we got from `users`, into the Array `userArr`. And now in the description of the embed, every value of `userArr` (the usernames) gets seperated by `,`  (if there is only one there will be no comma). That is what the function `join(", ")` does.